# python 3.2 printing tables

Tags: python-idle, python-3.2

I'm learning Python and attempting to write a program but I can't figure out how to I should write it.

Given the problem:

> "Use function "computeTax(status, taxableIncome):" to write a program that prints a tax table for taxable income from $50000-$60000 with intervals of $50 for all four statuses, as follows:

```
taxable income/   single/    married joint/   married seperate/   head of house/   
50000/             8688/       6665/              8688/               7352/  
50050/             8700/       6673/              8700/               7365/              
...                                                                  
59950/            11175/       8158/             11175/               9840/  
60000/            11188/       8165/             11188/               9852/
```

I don't understand how this works at all.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: The tax computation

```
def computeTax(status,taxableIncome):
    """
    status is a string such as 'married joint', taxableIncome is the amount of income
    This function returns the portion of the income that should be paid as tax. This amount is different  depending on the status.
    """
    status_multupliers = {blah} #a dictionary of status to multiplier mappings...
    return taxableIncome * status_multipliers[status]
```

Step2: initialise your file:

open a file for writing ('w').
write the heading line

Step3: fun with loops

```
for i in range(however_many_lines_you_want_in_your_table):
    income = 50*i #since we are going up in 50s
    current_line = ''     # this is what you want to write to your file
    for status in statuses: #statuses is a list of the available statuses. make this
        tax = computeTax(status,income)
        current_line += tax + '\'
    current_line += '\n'
    file.write(current_line)   #add the line
```

I've assumed that formatting doesn't matter too much.

For now on when asking questions on Stack Overflow please show a little bit of effort yourself. Otherwise you will be unlikely to get any help